# Fake "show 1 more comment"

Tags: bug, comments

What's happening to me is in this question: [How to populate a SQL in query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27280428/how-to-populate-a-sql-in-query/27285860)

When I load the page, I can see the *message* **show 1 more comment** but when I press it, there's no comment at all, and the *message* disappears until I load the page again.

Comment: See: [The system sees a comment that doesn't exist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/44249/262755). This is supposedly by design.

Comment: I guess it's a case of http://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: double secret comment

Comment: Well adding a comment and deleting it seems to fix the problem :)

Comment: @DavidG got it right.  It's an unavoidable race condition, basically.  It happens when someone deletes a comment after the page has already indicated to you that it exists.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Not sure this is true. The "1 more comment" link was there regardless of how many times the page was refreshed. I'm guessing it was some sort of cache issue and me adding/deleting fixed it.

Comment: @DavidG: [Comment counts are denormalized.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/44249/262755)  They're "almost real-time."  Well, they were in 2010, anyway.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Ya... still, SO could maintain the counts using triggers to make them accurate. Incrementing or decrementing an integer column doesn't exactly qualify as lots of CPU work. :-)

Comment: I was hoping to see a comment "show 1 more comment" that led here - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uxsWjeiQ76s

Comment: @Denis, but it takes a database lock out

Comment: What does "denormalised" actually mean, here?

Comment: The real problem is the whole hidden comment thing. I always want to see all the comments. This whole "click to see the actual comments" thing is a mistake.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm guessing it means that the record in the `Posts` table has a column called `CommentCount` (for example) rather than actually counting the number of comments in the `PostComments` table. That's how the number can get out of sync.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit In fact looking at [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new) it seems that's exactly how it works (assuming the tables follow the same format in the live system as opposed to this archive)

Comment: @DavidG: Right, okay

Comment: @matt: I saw a post with 159 comments once, and they weren't removed until I flagged them two years after they'd been posted. I was glad that most of them were hidden.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Okay, you have me there! I can see how the ability to toggle the hiddenness of a bunch of comments at once can be good. However, I still want the default to be showing, not hidden. Let me hide them if I want to, but don't force me to click just to see them. Every. Blasted. Time.