# "show X more comments" not doing anything

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments

This question:  [How to check if my string contains commas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37155382/594235)

It says *"show 2 more comments"* under the question...

[image]

Then when I click on the link, the link disappears and the comments do not show up...

[image]

Refreshing the page simply brings back the *"show 2 more comments"* link and I get the same results in all browsers I've tried.  It's isolated to this question as the *"show X more comments"* link is working fine on other postings.  As others have said, maybe related to caching, although a bug IMO.

Comment: Caching, I'd bet. Caching of deleted comments. (90% sure this _exact_ question has come up before, as well.)

Comment: Can reproduce on this question.  related/dupe: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306333/show-more-comment-link-broken

Comment: @NathanOliver, however, notice the other [meta question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306333/show-more-comment-link-broken) was tagged with [tag:status-norepro], meaning the developers could not reproduce the bug.  This one here is so far completely reproducible.

Comment: @Sparky Which leads me to believe that caching was to blame and before someone could look at it the cache caught up which was the assumption of the dev.

Comment: @NathanOliver, still a bug, no?  After all, if that's the case, this scenario could probably be avoided by forcing a cache dump when the comments are deleted.  Not sure.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I just fixed the count here. What happened was the 4 comments on the post weren't deleted simultaneously. They were deleted *almost* simultaneously. This causes a race condition. The deletion dates were:

```
2016-05-11 07:29:36.790
2016-05-11 07:29:36.807
2016-05-11 07:29:36.807
2016-05-11 07:29:36.807
```

So the moderator deleted the first comment, then clicked the "remove all" option. The remove all loop and the single deletion both loaded a post object with a particular comment count. The racing decrementing that followed is a fact of life at scale and you can either lock on it *all* of the time for accuracy. Or sacrifice that for performance - we choose the latter since it a) *very* rarely happens, b) is even more rarely noticed, and c) we can easily correct it (and do so in a nightly job).

Comment: Wait what does the [status-completed] tag mean here? Nobody fixed anything...

Comment: @Laurel I fixed the comment count on the post.

Comment: But it will happen again, if I understand what you said about the system. Isn't it [status-bydesign]? (I'm just curious, and I wasn't trying to say that this particular instance wasn't resolved, BTW.)

Comment: @Laurel lalalalal status-norepo lalalalala

Comment: This happened again [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54001879/how-to-pass-string-from-a-view-to-a-controller-in-mvc), which seemed to be from a user getting destroyed. This doesn't seem to be a *very* rare occurrence, because I've seen it happen rather often, users being destroyed may be one of them.

Comment: Same happend also here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3532958/regarding-a-question-in-elementary-number-theory

Comment: @NickCraver look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60068819/what-is-when-declaring-prop-in-vuejs)

Comment: [Happens here too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55035979/how-do-i-create-gtk2-style-widgets-in-gtk3)

Comment: Has still happened a lot to me, this year. Last time was today.

Comment: Same here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64742081/predicate-logic-in-coq

Answer (score 0):

The bug still exists in May 2020 and can be rather annoying if there is a high chance that it is a reply on a comment you left there. So to me the best **actual solution** is the one [suggested by DavidG (on a dup post)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278448/fake-show-1-more-comment#comment124652_278448):

1. Add another comment
2. Delete it

Maybe with a link to here, something like

```
dummy comment to rework a [bug](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/322853/2932052)
```

Comment: Or, better yet, leave Nick Craver a comment with a link to every post you find it on, so the "it's a rare occurrence" can be discarded and we get a patch

Comment: @Zoe Excuse me if this question seems stupid to you: Are you completely serious or have I annoyed you with something?

Comment: I'm serious. Linking all occurrences to [an employee](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/13249/nick-craver) could make enough work to prompt a patch (no problem = no work) so we don't need to deal with manual comments to force refresh the cache, or poke employees to fix it.

Answer (score -2):

Inspecting the headers in your browser shows that you can get a direct realtime link to the comment feed.

The [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/37155382/comments?_=1462987066400) for the linked question are empty.

The [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1642035/comments?_=1462988598700) for a popular question.

The "remaining comment count" is pulled from these data attributes:

```
            <tbody data-remaining-comments-count="2"
                   data-canpost="false"
                   data-cansee="true"
                   data-comments-unavailable="false"
                   data-addlink-disabled="true">
```

I can't find where they're populated in the full.en.js file, which suggests to me that it's populated server-side and probably a caching issue on their end.

Comment: I don't particularly care about these comments or dispute they may have been deleted along the way.  I'm reporting display of the *"show X more comments"* link as a bug when clicking it does nothing.

Comment: @Sparky Then downvote my answer. I'm just showing people that the comments don't exist, hence it's a caching issue on the server side.

Comment: @user6321384 You should probably explain this in your answer. It's hard to understand why you mention these 2 links without any context. And it looks like the second link is wrong, it leads to a question while the first link is probably a feed.

Comment: @A.L Thanks, didn't realize the second link was wrong.