# Answer says there's 2 comments but none load up

Tags: bug, comments

so looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39459833/1028804) at the bottom it shows me that there are 2 comments

[image: 2 comments]

but when i click the link none load up

[image: nothing]

I am aware that some comments were deleted and even after i cleared my cache the same thing happens so i'm not sure if this bug is that it's trying to load up deleted comments, or if 2 comments that weren't deleted aren't showing up when they should

I am running Chrome 53.0.2785.101 m on Windows 7

Comment: Repro-ed on Safari on iOS, so it is not a browser/client cache issue.

Comment: This is a known issue that crops up now and again... trying to find a relevant MSE/MSO post

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322853/show-x-more-comments-not-doing-anything