# Spam/Offensive-deleted answer is still showing "Show more comments" link, until you click it

Tags: bug, comments, deleted-answers, spam, rude-or-abusive

I noticed some odd behavior on [this "deleted as offensive" answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41030893/1835379):

When I load the page, it tells me *"comments are disabled on deleted / locked posts / reviews"*, but it gives me the option to *"show **9** more comments"*:

[image]

Now, when I click the *"show **9** more comments"* link, it changes its mind, and tells me I'm not allowed to load them, after all:

[image]

That message should probably be shown on page load, instead of making me curious about the comments.

Browser: Google Chrome (54.0.2840.99)
I've disabled all userscripts.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334417/answer-says-theres-2-comments-but-none-load-up http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322853/show-x-more-comments-not-doing-anything

Comment: Nice finds, @MikeM. Does this mean it requires manual intervention from a mod to fix this specific case?

Comment: That's pretty much what I gather. Given [Jon's comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334417/answer-says-theres-2-comments-but-none-load-up#comment394410_334417) on that first one, it sounds like a "meh, if/when we get to it" problem.

Comment: I don't think a mod can do it. It would probably require a developer, given Nick's answer. Definitely [status-urgent], though. Something is wrong with the presentation of a deleted spam answer!

Comment: @CodyGray: _"The presentation of the count amount deleted comments on a deleted spam answer"_, you mean? Serious business!

Comment: This is so incredibly important.

Comment: There, I made your question no longer repro'able ;)

Comment: "nice to meatspni" nice.

Comment: @BhargavRao - That isn't really helpful, because it is an issue and now you have removed the verifiable example. You should avoid being too heavy handed.

Comment: I wanted to see the offensive answer :(

Comment: @TravisJ, Nope not really. The timeline is visible to all mods. To repro. Create a spam post, Create 5+ comments on that, Flag the post as spam, Get a mod to "destroy" the user. And BAM! you've got your magical comments. I'm sure that the devs have more tools than us to investigate the issue.

Comment: The mods can still see it is a good reason I suppose. Sometimes it is easy to forget that comments are only invisible to normal users. I am going to take the suggestion to create a spam post as a joke :) I mean, why would *I* create a spam post when there are already so many of them in the wild? :P