# A comment I made disappeared but it doesn't look like it was deleted

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments

I'm easily the first guy around these parts to harp on the fact that comments are temporal, and I well beyond accept that, but I'm running into an awkward UI issue with a comment I had made prior.

Looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53773740/1079354), I know I left a single comment there to explain why I had closed that as a dupe.  I see that there's another commentator on there, so my natural inclination is to expand the comment list.

[image]

...but when I do, I don't see the comment I made and the "show 1 more comment" link is superfluous.

[image]

While I hold my tongue on why the comment was deleted, not being able to revisit it when the UI thinks I can is definitely jarring UX.  Could this get looked into?

Comment: (Now I run the risk of invalidating the ability to test this because I guarantee we're going to get a fly-by-night person to reopen the question.)

Comment: It's almost certainly the auto-generated comment that is posted when first suggesting a duplicate, and that is auto-deleted when the question is actually closed.  So it being deleted was correct (and automatic).

Comment: @Servy:  I don't think it is...I had posted my comment *after* I had closed it, so I'm not convinced that this is the automatic text for it.

Comment: All but that remaining comment were deleted by a moderator. Given the timestamp shown on that remaining comment it does seem strange that there would be a phantom "show 1 more comment" link, since the deletion happened a few hours prior.

Comment: @BoltClock:  Well, at least I know I'm not going crazy, then.  I had figured it *was* deleted (and again I hold my tongue), but I suppose that we also agree that the phantom link shouldn't be appearing here as well.  Would it be worth locking the post so that it could be reproduced *just* to guard against that fly-by-night case?

Comment: Possibly related: [Answer says there's 2 comments but none load up](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334417/4639281)

Comment: @Makoto: I threw a 60-minute lock on just in case. I dare not even add a comment or edit the post to link to this. I do recognize this bug having been reported before, though, so finding the existing report might aid investigations.

Comment: @TinyGiant:  Definitely looks related, but was also claimed to be fixed back in '16...

Comment: It was marked as status completed in may 2016 then it came back again in September 2016. I think the status completed was just the fixing of that particular post's comment count and the race condition detailed by nick still exists.

Comment: 60 minutes probably isn't nearly long enough, but if the community wants it reopened...

Comment: (Yeah, well, the community can be wrong.  And often is when it comes to *some* reopening requests.  /curmudgeon)

Comment: It happened to me too. I am not sure where I read it but posting another comment and deleting it resolved the issue.

Comment: Found it: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278448/fake-show-1-more-comment#comment124652_278448

Comment: @BoltClock If a dev hasn't had time to look into this yet, it might be worth putting a longer lock on the post and just re-posting a version of it, if people actually want to participate in the actual question.

Comment: @Makoto The status-completed of that question was simply because it was fixed for that one post. The cause here is a race condition when comments get deleted, and outside of updating the count for comments on a scheduled task (which would be quite the waste of resources), there *isn't* a fix for this. That's the nature of race conditions.

Comment: @animuson So if the intent is to not fix the bug (which is fair enough, some bugs aren't worth fixing), perhaps status by design would be better than completed?

Comment: @animuson couldn't you make the operations atomic? This seems like a rather silly race condition to have.

Comment: @TinyGiant don't make animuson go nuclear ... you'll regret it ...

Comment: @animuson I changed it to status by design,  so it's expected behaviour and so people don't think it was fixed,